# API Olist - access blocked by CORS policy

Tags: javascript, ajax, api, callback

Preciso utilizar a API Olist, através de uma callback, porém estou obtendo erro ao realizar a requisição POST que retornaria o access_token.

[image: erro]

O fluxo seria:

1. Utilizar a callback/getlink para enviar o client_id via GET para https://id-sandbox.olist.com/openid/authorize
2. A https://id-sandbox.olist.com/openid/authorize abre automaticamente a callback/olist?code=coderetornado&&secret=secretretornado
3. A callback/olist requisita via POST o access_token, enviando o secret e o code retornados no passo 2
4. Com o retorno do passo 3, a callback/olist salva o access_token no banco de dados para utilizar

Porém no passo 3, não consigo enviar a requisição POST pelo navegador, retornando o erro da imagem anterior. Utilizando o POSTMAN e enviando os dados direto para a API eu consigo, mas é necessário passar pela callback/olist para salvar o token.
Na requisição GET, utilizei o dataType: 'jsonp', assim evitando o CORS, mas na requisição POST não é possível utilizá-lo.

O código para a requisição é:

```
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        method: 'post',
        dataType: 'json',
        processData: false,
        data: function(){
            var formDataAuth = new FormData();
            configJson = JSON.parse('<?= $configJson ?>');
            formDataAuth = new FormData();
            formDataAuth.append('client_id', configJson.code);
            formDataAuth.append('grant_type', 'authorization_code');
            formDataAuth.append('client_secret', configJson.secret);
            formDataAuth.append('redirect_uri', configJson.callback);
            formDataAuth.append('code', configJson.key);
            return formDataAuth;
        }(),
        success: function(data) {
            savetoken(data);
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function(data) {
            console.log('erro', data);
        },
    });
```

O erro acontece por faltar alguma informação na requisição? Pode ocorrer por não possuir um SSL? Ou por outro motivo?

Answer (score 0):

O erro apresentado não é por falta de informação na requisição. Este é um erro de CORS, você está tentando fazer uma requisição para outro servidor/domínio que não é o seu, leia mais em https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

O CORS é tratado no back-end do servidor para o qual você está fazendo a requisição e não em seu código front-end

Comment: Então não há nada que eu possa fazer para tratar isto, certo?

Comment: esse site para o qual você está fazendo a requisição é seu? Ele é uma API com chave de acesso? acredito que deve haver alguma seção na documentação deles sobre CORS

Comment: É uma API, Olist é o nome. https://dev.olist.com/docs/authentication essa é a documentação, procurei mas não achei nada